# How can I change a numeric textbox value using code?

Tags: vue.js, kendo-ui, kendonumerictextbox

I have a numeric textbox as follows:

```html
<numeric-textbox id="value-field" :default-value="0.00" :min="0.00" :format="'n2'" :spinners="false" @change="amountChanged($event)" :disabled="amountDisabled" />
```

How can I set the value in code?

The things I've tried:

1. `$('#value-field').val(0.00);` - this works temporarily but changes back to the previous value when it gets the focus
2. I tried a model like `v-model="myValue"` but changing the value in code doesn't update the field.

I can't figure out what I need to do to get it to change!

Comment: I've used `v-model` and works. Maybe the issue is another part of your code. Check this demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/gzbkbk-maqc4a?file=src/main.vue

Comment: That's good confirmation. Thanks I'll investigate that angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `v-model` directive shorthand or `:value` bind and `@input` event. ([vue docs](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/v-model.html#_2-x-syntax))

FULL DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/gzbkbk-maqc4a?file=src/main.vue

---

- **With `v-model`:**

```html
<numerictextbox v-model="myValue" />
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    myValue: 5
  };
},
methods: {
  updateMyValueProgrammatically() {
    this.myValue = 10;
  }
}
```

- **With `:value` and `@input`:**

```html
<numerictextbox :value="myValue" @input="onInput" />
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    myValue: 5
  };
},
methods: {
  onInput(e) {
    this.myValue = e.target.value;
  },
  updateMyValueProgrammatically() {
    this.myValue = 10;
  }
}
```